# Broken held back packages

Tags: installation, apt, package-management

Since I upgraded to Precise 12.04, I've been having troubles with Unity3d, as my graphics card drivers don't seem to work. I've tried reinstalling them, downgrading them, and reinstalling unity. Whenever I try to do so, it won't let me, saying:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-tweak-tool : Depends: gnome-shell but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Does anyone know how to solve the broken packages problem? I've looked everywhere and I'm desperate. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: possible duplicated: [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/62483)

Answer (score 0):

The Debian release notes [include some good instructions](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#package-status) on disabling holds.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.